# Configuration of WCF service and accessing that service from one machine to another

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to set up a WCF service that accepts a simple string value and returns a string.  I followed the tutorial here --> [WCF Walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx) but I am trying to do one thing different from the example.  I am trying to communicate from my host machine running Windows 7 where the WcfServiceLibrary1 is running and I have confirmed it is working with the WCF Test Client and I get a response back - all is well.

I created a Forms application, as described in the sample, and I referenced the local address of my host machine by executing netstat from command prompt.  That returned 192.168.1.104 so I plugged the link below into my ServiceReference in my Forms application and the service was found.

```
http://192.168.1.104:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/mex
```

I ran my WCF service on the Windows 7 machine and then I executed the Forms application on my XP Virtual Machine.  I invoked a call to the service by means of a button click with the code below, per the example.

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
    string response = client.GetData(txtData.Text);
    lblResponse.Text = response;
}
```

I am getting the following error and I am not sure how this can be solved.

```
  ERROR: There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/ that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.  INNER EXCEPTION: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8733
```

What is strange to me is why the IP address changed from the value I entered, which starts with 192, to localhost.

Any ideas?

Comment: Post the client section of the service reference in the forms application configuration file

Comment: JR, that's it!  Post that suggestion as an answer and I'll vote for it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client section of you service reference element in the forms application config file needs to be updated. It should look something similar to this:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://192.168.1.104:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/mex" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
</client>
```